# 4-Dimensional database grid

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Right now, I have a two-dimensional grid that shows the (1) requirements for a particular (2) service. It looks something like this on the front-end:

```
                FEATURE          TRAILER           MARKETING
DVD               x                
Streaming         x                x
Theatrical        x                                   x
```

How I am storing it now in the database is:

```
`service`
  - id
  - name (e.g., "DVD")

` requirements`
  - id
  - name (e.g., "Marketing")

`requirements_grid`
  - service_id
  - requirement_ids (csv of all requirement ids)
```

Now I can say describe something like, "For a DVD, I need a Feature as a requirement."

I now need to add two additional parameters, (3) content type; and (4) provider. These will be changes (additions or removals) from the default requirement grid.

This would allow me to describe something like "For a Television (content type) DVD for Fox (provider), I need a Feature and a Trailer.

How would I structure the database to store this? And also, what would be a possible way to display this on the front-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question - how to store a four dimensional grid - just continue in the direction you're already headed, but normalize the `requirement_ids` column.

So in the current schema, if you have

```
| service_id | requirement_ids |
|          1 |           1,2,3 |
|          2 |               2 |
```

In the new schema, you get:

```
| service_id | requirement_id |
|          1 |              1 |
|          1 |              2 |
|          1 |              3 |
|          2 |              2 |
```

After this change, adding new dimensions is really easy:

```
`service`
  - id
  - name (e.g., "DVD")

` requirements`
  - id
  - name (e.g., "Marketing")

`content_type`
  - id
  - name

`provider`
  - id
  - name

`requirements_grid`
  - service_id
  - requirement_id
  - content_type_id
  - provider_id
```

I can't help you with the other question. Consider moving it to a separate Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and explanation. Would it be possible with the above structure to 'inherit' a default service x requirement template? Basically, all of the `content_type` and `provider` changes are based on this default template. (so for example, we might have 100 services, and one provider might have everything in the default template, with the exception of a single removal for a single service.

Comment: Well... you can either just create a template by inserting rows for a fictitious item that is the template, and then copy the associated rows whenever you need the template. Otherwise you'll wind up with a more complex schema where the grid represents differences from a given template. That is indeed possible too, but which one you should go with really depends on how you intend to use it.

Comment: The first approach will give you a lot of redundancy. The second approach may perform slightly worse and is more complex to implement.

Comment: in that case, how would requirements be removed from the default template? In the above scenario, it would only be possible to add.

Comment: You can just add an extra field to ``requirements_grid`` that indicates whether the given requirement is being added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE requirement
(service_id INT NOT NULL
requirement_id INT NOT NULL
content_type --type??
provider --type??,
PRIMARY KEY ? (service_id,requirement_id,content_type,provider type));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the schema I chose to go with based on feedback:

```
`requirements_grid`
  - service_id NOT NULL
  - requirement_ids (csv of all requirement ids) NOT NULL
  - content_type
  - provider
```

Keeping the csv field just makes it a little easier to access for me.